# Close listed executable in C++, code executes once instead of continuously scanning

Tags: c++

Hi guys I am a beginner in C++ and I wrote code to attempt to close a listed process (i.e.,):

```
 char* chos[3] = {"launcher.exe","cheat.exe","lol.exe"};
```

The problem is that my code only works once (when first loaded) rather than continuously like I would like it. If possible, I would like this code to monitor the list of currently running processes and close my predefined exe name when it is spawned.

```
#include "StdInc.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void find_Proc() {

    HANDLE proc_Snap;
    HANDLE proc_iw4;
    HANDLE proc_iw4term;

    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32iw4;

    int i;
    char* chos[3] = {"launcher.exe","cheat.exe","lol.exe"};

    char* iw4m = "iw4m.exe";

    proc_iw4 = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    proc_Snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    pe32iw4.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    for(i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {

        Process32First(proc_Snap , &pe32);
        do {
            if(!strcmp(chos[i],pe32.szExeFile)) {
                MessageBox(NULL,"CHEAT DETECTED","ERROR",NULL);
                Process32First(proc_iw4,&pe32iw4);
                do {
                    if (!strcmp(iw4m,pe32iw4.szExeFile)) {
                        proc_iw4term =  OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, pe32iw4.th32ProcessID);
                        if (proc_iw4term != NULL)
                            TerminateProcess(proc_iw4term, 0);
                        CloseHandle(proc_iw4term);
                    }
                } while(Process32Next(proc_iw4, &pe32iw4));
            }
        } while(Process32Next(proc_Snap, &pe32));
    }

    CloseHandle(proc_Snap);
    CloseHandle(proc_iw4);
    //scanf("sadas",&i);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you are asking (I guess English is not your first language? No problem). Is this correct: You want to constantly monitor the currently running processes, and if one of them is in a pre-defined list, force it to close?

Comment: i use this code to scan task manager process to find what App runned that i listed in my code if that App runned so do force close iw4m.exe. but its just scan process one time (when i load this code) i need scan process full time (until i stopped this code)

Comment: Hey all, I think I fixed the English. That is my best guess with what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: yes thank you (sorry for my bad)

Comment: Where and how do you call `find_Proc` function ?

Comment: Do you call find_Proc repeatedly? BTW, in C++ chos is `const char*[3]`.

Comment: Why do you create two snapshots? One would be sufficient. Also your code would perform better if your outer loop is doing the Process32Next and the inner loop is for i and doing the strcmp.

Comment: Are you asking us to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two possibilities here:

1. Run your existing code in a loop, with a sleep for say 30 seconds between each check for "bad" processes.  Make the sleep as long as you can, to avoid interfering more than necessary with power management etc.
2. Hook the actual Windows process creation.  For example, see here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11985/Hooking-the-native-API-and-controlling-process-cre or use the Microsoft Detours library to insert your own code before processes are started.